# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 14 Exercise 2 - Elements by Tag Name - Why Isn't Recursion Working?

Tags: javascript, recursion

In Chapter 14 of Eloquent Javascript (3rd Edition), the second exercise is to create a function `byTagName` that works like `document.getElementsByTagName`. The function should take a node and return all child elements with a given tag name.

My function should take a node and a tag name, then put each of the node's children in a holding array if the child matches the tag name. Then the function tries to concatenate the holding array with the result of calling itself recursively on each of the node's children. Finally, it returns the holding array.

My function isn't recursing correctly. Can anyone tell me why?

```js
//THE FUNCTION THAT ISN'T WORKING:

function byTagName(node, tagName) {
  let elements = [];
  let tag = tagName.toUpperCase();
  for (let child of node.children) {
    if (tag == child.nodeName) {
      elements.push(child);
    }
    elements.concat(byTagName(child, tagName));
    //^This part isn't working. 
    //I think the recursive call to byTagName is returning nothing no matter what.
  }
  return elements;
}


console.log(byTagName(document.body, "h1").length);
// → Correctly logs "1"
console.log(byTagName(document.body, "span").length);
// → Should log 3, but logs "0"
let para = document.querySelector("p");
console.log(byTagName(para, "span").length);
// → Correctly logs "2"
```

```html
<h1>Heading with a <span>span</span> element.</h1>
<p>A paragraph with <span>one</span>, <span>two</span> spans.
</p>
```

Comment: `elements = elements.concat(byTagName(child, tagName));`

Comment: @Barmar ah, thanks!